# how to arrange lists inside dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

strong textI'm using the following declaration to arrange my lists inside a dictionary:

```
> train_dataset, test_dataset, valid_dataset = ({'image':[], 'mask':[]}
> for i in range(3))
```

and I need something like below as a result of

```
> "print(train_dataset[0])"
```

Do not worry about contents, but about {}'s and []'s.

```
> *{'image': array([[[*238, 238, 239, ..., 226, 227, 230],
>     [234, 238, 240, ..., 226, 227, 225],
>     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]],
>     ...,
>     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
>     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
>     [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8),  
> 'mask': array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>     [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>     [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>     ...,
>     [2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2],
>     [2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2],
>     [2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2]]], dtype=uint8)}
```

but I'm getting:

```
> *{'image': [array([[*40, 40, 40, ..., 59, 59, 59],
>     [40, 40, 40, ..., 59, 59, 59],
>     [40, 40, 40, ..., 59, 59, 59],
>     ...,
>     [42, 42, 42, ..., 41, 41, 41],
>     [42, 42, 42, ..., 41, 41, 41],
>     [42, 42, 42, ..., 41, 41, 41]], dtype=uint8),  
>array([[11, 11, 14, ..., 28, 34, 35],
>     [11, 12, 14, ..., 27, 32, 33],
>     [12, 12, 15, ..., 21, 21, 21],
>     ...,
>     [ 7,  7,  6, ..., 13, 19, 20],
>     [11, 11,  8, ..., 12, 20, 21],
>     [12, 12,  9, ..., 12, 20, 21]], dtype=uint8),  
>array([[19, 19, 19, ..., 39, 39, 39],
>     [19, 19, 19, ..., 39, 39, 39],
>     [19, 19, 19, ..., 39, 39, 39],
>     ...
>     ...,
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)]}
```

Comment: Hi @Wander Mendes, the code provided throws an error because `train_dataset` beeing a dictionnary it can't be sliced as in `train_dataset[0]`.
Can you correct the example so that we may reproduce the problem ?